# Calling 'static constexpr bool template function' in other template function is impossible?

Tags: c++, templates, constexpr

I'm trying to call the 'static constexpr template function' in the 'template class' from the 'other template function'.

I thought it would be hard to explain in words, so I shortened the code structure and brought the code.

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

enum class eComponentCategory
{
    foo,
    bar
};


//class for type classification
template <class BaseComponentType, eComponentCategory _category>
class Component
{
public:
    Component() {};
    virtual ~Component() {};

    static constexpr eComponentCategory category = _category;

    template <class CompareType>
    static constexpr bool IsBaseComponentType()
    {
        return std::is_same_v<BaseComponentType, CompareType>;
    }
};

class FooComponent
    : public Component<FooComponent, eComponentCategory::foo>
{
public:
    FooComponent() {}
    virtual ~FooComponent() {}
};


class ComponentHolder
{
public:
    ComponentHolder() {};
    virtual ~ComponentHolder() {};

    template <class ComponentType>
    ComponentType* GetComponent()
    {
        ComponentType* retCom = nullptr;

        //type check
        if constexpr (ComponentType::IsBaseComponentType<ComponentType>())
//compile time error  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        {
            //do Something
        }

        return retCom;
    }

};


int main()
{
    ComponentHolder holder{};

    holder.GetComponent<FooComponent>();


    return 0;
}
```

This code causes compilation error:
C2760: syntax error: unexpected token ‘)’, expected ‘statement’
C3878: syntax error: unexpected token ')' following 'selection_statement'

Q1. As far as I know, the holder.GetComponent() function that calls within the main function is determined at the time of compilation, but it seems not in real, so I'd like to know what I'm mistaken about.

Q2. Since RTTI is not allowed in my project, I think I need to do the compilation time type check in the similar way as above, is there an alternative?

Comment: MSVC is being unhelpful as usual, see Clang's error: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/8W93T79sE Also one question per question please.

Comment: TL;DR of the dupe: `if constexpr (ComponentType::IsBaseComponentType<ComponentType>())` needs to be `if constexpr (ComponentType::template IsBaseComponentType<ComponentType>())`

Comment: Your code compiles if you write `ComponentType::template IsBaseComponentType<ComponentType>()`. See also [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/610245/5740428). Does that answer your question?

Comment: *"I thought it would be hard to explain in words"* -- Not that hard. I'd adjust some of the word choices, but what your opening paragraph is mostly missing is a statement that you are getting a compilation error (plus the error message). What I would advise is taking some time to simplify your code. It looks like you have more infrastructure than should be necessary to reproduce the error. *For example, does `GetComponent` need to be a member function? If you defined it outside a class, can you still get the error? Also, why must an `enum` be defined? why not an `int` or drop that parameter?*

Comment: @JanSchultke Oh, I had no idea that I could put the template keyword in there. Thank you.